# Combined image from List<Bitmap> images not appearing in ImageColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, radgridview

On my current project, there are several instances where a row of indicators (using 26x26 PNG icons) is required.  In this case, it's a `DataGridView` (more specifically, a Telerik `RadGridView`). The images are loaded from the resource file and are present.

My current code defines these indicators as a row is created:

```
Bitmap indicators;
List<Bitmap> content = new List<Bitmap>();

if (l.Condition1 == true)
    content.Add(myProj.Properties.Resources.One);
if (l.Condition2 == true)
    content.Add(myProj.Properties.Resources.Two);
if (l.Condition3 == true)
    content.Add(myProj.Properties.Resources.Three);

if (content.Count() != 0)
{
    int width = content.Select(w => w.Width).Sum();
    indicators = new Bitmap(width, 26);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(indicators))
    {
        int origin = 0;
        foreach (Bitmap p in content)
        {
            g.DrawImage(p, new Point(origin, 0));
            origin += p.Width;
        }

        row.Cells[15].Value = indicators;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work (the images don't display at all) and I can't quite sort out what I've missed. Assigning an image to the `Value` property works if I just load one image and don't use the loop.  What have I overlooked that is preventing this from working and these indicators displaying?

Comment: What doesn't work? The images don't display? They are misaligned? Not drawn correctly?

Comment: The images don't display at all.

Comment: Side notes: You should `Dispose` of the images in `content`, if `.Value` contains an image you should `Dispose` of that, there is no need for `== true`, `content` is a list so just use `Count` i.e. no braces, You can use `Sum` directly no need for the `Select`, probably best to use `Max` height instead of the hard coded magic number `26` and then centre the images and you should declare `inidcators` in the scope it is used in i.e. the `if` block where you initialise it; unless you use it elsewhere of course.

Comment: Save `indicators` to disk after you've drawn then images to it and see what it looks like.

Comment: The `"== true"` is required because those values are actually `bool?` not `bool`.  The 26 is there because a real-estate hard limit on pixels is required, and will probably be replaced by a constant. `indicators` will see further use once this is working. Good catch on the superfluous `()` and `Select` though.   The images in `content` are disposed further down the code.  Unfortunately, none of these changes actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Making them nullable seems a bit odd but okay, if it is needed I'd set it as a constant and scale the images to the correct height though. I didn't think they'd fix the issue hence why I started the comment with `Side notes`.

Comment: Usually when I have such problems I'm missing a Refresh/Repaint somewhere.

Comment: The image is assigned as a value to the row before the row is appended to the `RadGridView` `RowCollection`